# Parametro passado por valor sendo modificado como referencia

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte situação, tenho um objeto com valor 2800, quando passo esse objeto **por valor** e divido o valor de um atributo do objeto dentro do escopo da função, o valor do meu objeto também muda como se eu tivesse passado por referência.

Segue um exemplo:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Double Valor { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionController
{
    public void ProccessCreditCardPayment(){
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.Valor = 2800;
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice(transaction); //passando parâmetro por valor

        Debug.WriteLine(transaction.Valor); //valor = 28, ele foi modificado no outro metodo e influenciou no meu objeto fora do escopo da função

    }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public Double Valor{get;set;}
    public Invoice(Transaction transaction){ //parametro por valor            
        transaction.Valor = transaction.Valor/100;
        this.Valor = transaction.Valor;
    }
}
```

Não consigo entender o porque isso está acontecendo,para mim não tem sentido algum.

Segue link explicando em C passagem por valor e por referencia: https://www.ime.usp.br/~elo/IntroducaoComputacao/Funcoes%20passagem%20de%20parametros.htm

Comment: O "valor" que é passado por parâmetro é um apontador para o objeto, então, ao alterar o objeto dentro do método, o de fora também vai ser alterado.

Comment: Mas eu não passei por referencia...

Comment: Mesmo eu não deixando explicito `ref` ele se comporta como referencia? nao tem sentido para mim

Comment: Quase isso. Leia a publicação que eu marquei como duplicada que você vai entender.

Comment: Segue um exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0yRYzw

Comment: @LINQ agora entendi, o comportamento é diferente quando se usa tipos complexos pois ele copia, porém ambas com o mesmo endereço de memória